# Convert jArray to Object

Tags: .net, json, vb.net

I have a JSON array I want to convert to my User object using json.net.

jArray1 = ["First","Last",12345]

```
Public Class User
    Public FirstName as String
    Public LastName as String
    Public UserId as Integer
End Class
```

I have tried

```
MyUser = jArray1.ToObject(Of User)
```

which gives me this error: 
Cannot deserialize the current JSON array into type 'User' because the type requires a JSON object

What am I missing?

The error message also says: JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.

But I cant work out how to do that. :\

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of problems. One is that you must deserialize to a collection of `User`s, not a single `User`.

Your next problem is that your array contains only arbitrary items. Two strings and and Integer. How will the mechanism know that you want the string "First" in the `User.FirstName` property, and so on?

I don't know how you are obtaining that `JArray`, but this is basically what you want:

```
Dim json = "[{ 'FirstName' : 'First', 'LastName' : 'Last', 'UserId' : 1234 }]"
Dim jar = JArray.Parse(json)
Dim usr = jar.ToObject(Of List(Of User))
```

Comment: Unfortunately I cant control the json I receive. The position in the array determines the property. I can manually assign the array elements to the object but I thought there should be a more elegant solution.

Comment: There may be a JsonProperty attribute that you can decorate your properties with to help you but I honestly doubt it. I think you are stuck with inelegance.